# Double length inefficient PRG

Tags: pseudo-random-generator

Is there a known example of a deterministic algorithm that given an n-bit input returns 2n-bit output, and where a random output can't be efficiently distinguished from a random 2n bit string?

Comment: Deterministic? I don't know, but see MeshHash2: https://eprint.iacr.org/2009/232 -- See page 15

Comment: So you're looking for literally any length doubling PRG?